# Design patterns on Action Script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to improve my knowledge of Action Script 3, I was thinking if there were some resources or advanced books regarding designs.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to learning as3 design patterns then "O'Reilly ActionScript 3.0 Design Patterns: Object Oriented Programming Techniques by William Sanders & Chandima Cumaranatunge" is a must in my opinion. It covers creational, structural, behavioral and multiple patterns for as3.

You can find a link to it on amazon here:

[http://www.amazon.com/ActionScript-3-0-Design-Patterns-Programming/dp/0596528469/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1302465324&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528469)

Comment: @critrus mark this answer as correct, as it is. I personally own this book and completely agree.

Comment: This is indeed and excellent AS3 specific book. I also learned quite a bit from O'Reilly's "Head First: Design Patterns". This Head First book is admittedly a bit on the "for dummies" side in terms of writing style, and I normally wouldn't go for that sort of thing, but for this particular topic I made an exception because the subject isn't one I'm especially enthusiastic about and the GoF book is a *very* dull read if you're not in love with design patterns.

Comment: This is the book for as3 design patterns for sure.